# PE4: Largest Palindrome Product (Clojure)

Tags: programming-challenge, clojure, lisp, palindrome

I solved [Project Euler 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) using Clojure Lisp.

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>   Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

I'm not very experienced with Clojure yet. I tried to break the logic down into small, easy to understand functions. I added documentation and input type assertions to each function.

How can I improve this code? Is `:pre` a good method for asserting correct input types, or is there a better way of doing that?

```clj
(defn palindrome? [arg]
  "Returns true if arg is a palindrome, i.e., it reads the same both ways"
  (= (seq (str arg))
     (reverse (str arg))))

(defn pow [N X]
  "Returns N to the power of X"
  {:pre [(number? N) (number? X)]}
  (reduce * (repeat X N)))

(defn nums-with-n-digits [digits]
  "Return list of all numbers comprised of a certain number of digits"
  {:pre (number? digits)}
  (let [max (pow 10 digits)
        min (/ max 10)]
    (range min max)))

(defn products-of-nums-list [nums]
  "Returns a descending order list of distinct products of each of the numbers in nums"
  {:pre (list? nums)}
  (sort > (distinct (for [x nums y nums] (* x y)))))

(defn solve-pe4 [digits]
  "Returns list of solutions of largest palindrome products of all numbers with a certain number of digits"
  {:pre (number? digits)}
  (first (filter palindrome? (products-of-nums-list (nums-with-n-digits digits)))))

(defn -main []
  (println (solve-pe4 2)) ; 9009
  (println (solve-pe4 3))); correct answer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function's docstring must go [before its argument vector](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#docstring-after-fn-name). You've written your docstrings after your argument vectors, which prevents your `:pre`conditions from being recognized and doesn't work when you try to retrieve the docstring with tools like [`doc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/doc):

```clj
(doc palindrome?)
;; -------------------------
;; user/palindrome?
;; ([arg])
;;   nil
```

Rather than explicitly calling `seq` in your `palindrome?` function, you could use [`clojure.string/reverse`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/reverse) and then just compare the two strings. Also, in Clojure code, if when you have something that could be anything, or something that could be any number, it's conventional to name it `x`:

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(defn palindrome?
  "Returns true iff x reads the same both ways in base ten."
  [x]
  (let [s (str x)]
    (= s (str/reverse s))))
```

In most cases, it's conventional to use lowercase instead of uppercase for names. Following from the rule of `x` above, if you have *two* things, each of which could be any number, it's conventional to name the second one `y`:

```clj
(defn pow
  "Returns x to the power of y."
  [x y]
  (reduce * (repeat y x)))
```

It's essential that the collection of `:pre`conditions you give in a `defn` be a *collection* of preconditions (such as the vector you have in your `pow` function), rather than just a single precondition (such as in your other three functions with preconditions). This is because, due to Clojure's homoiconicity, `(number? digits)` is, in fact, a collection (a list, to be precise) containing two elements: `number?` and `digits`. In this case, you can use `{:pre [(number? digits)]}` instead.

Your local `max` and `min` bindings shadow the existing [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) and [`min`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/min) functions in `clojure.core`, which is [generally a bad idea](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#dont-shadow-clojure-core) because it can lead to confusion and forces you to use namespace-qualified names for those functions if you want to use them. Also, since you already use the name `n` in your function name (`nums-with-n-digits`), using `n` as your parameter name would allow you to simplify your function's docstring and body without sacrificing clarity:

```clj
(defn nums-with-n-digits
  "Return a lazy sequence of all positive integers with n digits."
  [n]
  (let [end (pow 10 n)
        start (/ end 10)]
    (range start end)))
```

If you move the docstring for `products-of-nums-list` and replace the condition map with `{:pre [(list? nums)]}`, you'll see that calls like `(products-of-nums-list (nums-with-n-digits 2))` will fail. This is because [`range`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) (and therefore `nums-with-n-digits`) doesn't return a list; it returns a [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4528/sequences#t=201608172316139934918). All lists are sequences, but not all sequences are lists. While `(range Long/MAX_VALUE)` returns instantly and uses negligible memory, `(apply list (range Long/MAX_VALUE))` will use all your computer's memory before it returns.

Your `products-of-nums-list` function is pretty scary, actually. Your use of `distinct` and `sort` causes first a set and then an array containing all of the distinct elements in `nums` to be held in memory. Try evaluating `(products-of-nums-list (nums-with-n-digits 4))` while watching your CPU and memory usage.

Rather than delegating the task of sorting (which is overkill anyway) to a `products-of-nums-list` function that isn't particularly general anyway, it would be better to just put the `for` directly into `solve-pe4` and use [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) instead of `sort` to get the final result:

```clj
(defn solve-pe4
  "Returns the largest palindrome made from the product of two n-digit numbers."
  [n]
  (->> (let [nums (nums-with-n-digits n)]
         (for [x nums
               y nums]
           (* x y)))
       (filter palindrome?)
       (apply max)))
```

This function is already quite readable, so I don't see a need to decompose it further. It significantly improves the performance of `(solve-pe4 3)` and, given enough time, can find solutions to larger problems:

```clj
(solve-pe4 4)
;;=> 99000099
```

Your `:pre`conditions are an OK way to assert correct input types. Clojure 1.9 will bring the [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) library, which is a far more powerful way to solve that problem (and others):

```clj
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/fdef pow
  :args (s/cat :x number? :y nat-int?)
  :ret number?)

(s/fdef nums-with-n-digits
  :args (s/cat :n pos-int?)
  :ret (s/coll-of pos-int?))

(s/fdef solve-pe4
  :args (s/cat :n pos-int?)
  :ret pos-int?)
```

You can use [`instrument`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec.test/instrument) to enable spec validation:

```clj
(require '[clojure.spec.test :as stest])

(stest/instrument)

(nums-with-n-digits 0)
;; clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to #'user/nums-with-n-digits did not conform to spec:
;;                             In: [0] val: 0 fails at: [:args :n] predicate: pos-int?
;;                             :clojure.spec/args  (0)
;;                             :clojure.spec/failure  :instrument
```

Comment: Wow that's a great answer, thanks for all the improvements!

Comment: There is one slightly unexpected behavior (to me) on your version of `palindrome?` function, in that it returns true for `(palindrome? nil)` is that intentional?

Comment: @Phrancis I only really intended for `palindrome?` to work on nonnegative integers. Looking at it again, though, I think that having `palindrome?` accept integers is needlessly complex; it would be better to have it just work with strings: `(s/fdef palindrome? :args (s/cat :s string?) :ret boolean?)` This would remove the `let` in its definition: `(defn palindrome? [s] (= s (str/reverse s)))` Then, in `solve-pe4`, you can simply replace `palindrome?` with `(comp palindrome? str)`.

Comment: I made a change and added `(cond (s/blank? s) false :else ...` which makes it work great for non-negative ints and strings and eliminates empty/nil from returning true

Comment: @Phrancis Personally, I would say that `""` *is* a palindrome because it reads the same both ways, but it's up to you.

Comment: Good point, I fixed that. I can't believe how much faster your method is, wow!

Comment: @Phrancis I wish I could figure out *why* it's so much faster. I'm guessing it has something to do with your use of `distinct` and `sort`, but none of my more precise hypotheses so far have stood up under further experimentation.